# async progress popup for a slow ASP postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

I have a page with an Update button which might take two seconds, or it might take five minutes to postback. The user doesn't know if it's going to timeout or when/if it'll come back with the success message. The codebehind is massive and I only maintain a small part of it.

I made a progress popup and put it on the page so I can show that it is processing #50 of 500 records, for example.

The popup uses a jQuery AJAX call to get a JSON object from a webmethod. The Success function sets a timer to repeat the call.

Status info is passed from the codebehind by putting it into HttpContext.Current.Cache. The webmethod retrieves it. It is my understanding that I can't have the webmethod use the Session because that blocks it from running asynchronously.

The page is async="true".

The AJAX call from jQuery has "async: true" in it.

The webmethod has the [WebMethod(false)] attribute.

The page still blocks the webmethod. I tried using HttpRuntime.Cache to store the status info, but that didn't change anything.

I fixed the issue by moving the WebMethod into an .asmx web service. Now it runs asynchronously.

I'm just curious if there was something I was missing. I think it's crazy that I can specify "async" all over the place but my webmethod doesn't run asynchronously unless I put it in a completely different page. And that would always run asynchronously, right? So what's the point in specifying async?

Comment: SignalR would definitely be the easiest approach. Is that an option?

Comment: I looked into it, but that seemed like a lot more extra code than just moving the webmethod to an .asmx file. The webmethod only takes about 25 ms so speed isn't a problem. But SignalR looks interesting and I'm going to try to find an excuse to use SignalR in the future.